# Delete blobs Performance with Azure Storage .NET SDK

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-blob-storage

I am trying to query containers and delete blobs inside it based on blob `LastModifiedTime`.

This is my approach

a) `ListContainers(null, ContainerListingDetails.None)` API to get containers

b) `ListBlobs(null, true);` API to get blobs

c) Then for each blob based on modified time, issue a `Delete` call

The performance is quite horrible with 100 containers and ~30K blobs in each. So, I decided to parallel container deletes. It improved but still slow.

As you can see, in LIST API I'm not fetching blob details to avoid more data transfer.

Questions

a) Does Azure Storage SDK wait for blob to get fully deleted when `Delete` request is made or does it return right away when server returns `202 (Accepted)` ? (Delete is async operation based on Azure Storage REST API)

b) Is there a better approach for doing the above ? With the release of [Storage lifecycle management](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/azure-blob-storage-lifecycle-management-public-preview/), may be setting retention policy would be ideal.